# Is Homebrew ready for High Sierra?

Tags: macos, homebrew

The [requirements](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation.html#2) page for [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) lists a lower bound (10.10, in late Sep 2017) for the version of macOS, but no upper bound is listed.

Is Homebrew ready for High Sierra? Better yet, can you confirm that you have successfully used it to have a more complete/recent development ecosystem on High Sierra?

Comment: I upgraded to High Sierra Beta from Sierra and my homebrew is failing to work properly. A fresh reinstall of it may do the trick.

Comment: Reinstallation (on top of the existing install) failed. But uninstallation and then a fresh install worked fine.

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of permissions issues... i'll try a fresh install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully installed a new package in Homebrew after upgrading to High Sierra, and the package is working. I had to upgrade Xcode first.

Comment: It works, but my httpd + php7 setup is now giving me very strange errors and segmentation faults when running Magento 2 sites. Everything else is working fine. I think the reason may be that PHP is now build with thread safety and i guess theres a conflict with php70-intl module (or something on these lines). Not sure it is fixable (yet).